# Insert data in 2 tables with the last inserted ID of the parent table must also be inserted in the child table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I tried with the code below. The record is inserted but the parent ID is not.
The last inserted ID of the parent table must also be inserted in the child table the same time when submit button is clicked.
Thanks.

**Controller:**

```
public function insert_doc_control_review(Request $request)
{
    $form_data = array(
        'comment' => $request->comment,
        'assigned_to' => $request->assigned_to,
        'revision' => $request->revision,
        'file_id' => $request->file_id,
        'attachment' => $request->attachment,
        'phase_id' => $request->phase_id,
        'review_date' => $request->review_date,
        'due_date' => $request->due_date,
        'completed_date' => $request->completed_date,
        'user_id'  =>  Auth::user()->id,
        'doc_number' => $this->getNextDocRevNumber()
    );

    DocumentControlReview::create($form_data);
    
    $lastId = DocumentControlReview::create($form_data);
    
    $archive_data = array(
        'user_id'  =>  Auth::user()->id,
        'iso_management_id' => $request->iso_management_id,
        'phase_id' => $request->phase_id,
        'document_control_review_id' => $request->document_control_review_id,
        'initial_approval_id' => $request->initial_approval_id,
        'review_id' => $request->review_id,
        'final_approval_id' => $request->final_approval_id,
        'awaiting_release_id'  => $request->awaiting_release_id,
        'release_id'  => $request->release_id,
        'project_id' => $request->project_id,
        'folder_id' => $request->folder_id,
        'file_id' => $request->file_id,
        $lastId
    );

    DocumentRecordArchive::create($archive_data);
}
```

Comment: i dint understand your last element in second array. Does this seem right?

Comment: also, can you show your create function code too.

Comment: you want to use newly created `DocumentControlReview`'s id on `DocumentRecordArchive`. right??

Comment: Yes that's right. I want to insert it in DocumentRecordArchive.

Comment: then check out the answer i provided. let me know if you don't understand anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write the code like below.

```
public function insert_doc_control_review(Request $request)
{
    $form_data = array(
        'comment' => $request->comment,
        'assigned_to' => $request->assigned_to,
        'revision' => $request->revision,
        'file_id' => $request->file_id,
        'attachment' => $request->attachment,
        'phase_id' => $request->phase_id,
        'review_date' => $request->review_date,
        'due_date' => $request->due_date,
        'completed_date' => $request->completed_date,
        'user_id'  =>  Auth::user()->id,
        'doc_number' => $this->getNextDocRevNumber()
    );
    
    $lastId = DocumentControlReview::create($form_data);
    
    $archive_data = array(
        'user_id'  =>  Auth::user()->id,
        'iso_management_id' => $request->iso_management_id,
        'phase_id' => $request->phase_id,
        'document_control_review_id' => $lastId->id, // Parent ID
        'initial_approval_id' => $request->initial_approval_id,
        'review_id' => $request->review_id,
        'final_approval_id' => $request->final_approval_id,
        'awaiting_release_id'  => $request->awaiting_release_id,
        'release_id'  => $request->release_id,
        'project_id' => $request->project_id,
        'folder_id' => $request->folder_id,
        'file_id' => $request->file_id,
        //'parent_id' => $lastId->id, there is document_control_review_id which I assume is the parent_id foreign column.
    );

    DocumentRecordArchive::create($archive_data);
}
```

look `lastId` is an object which holds the newly created data. you want to add this one's id in the child table. so use it's id attribute. i used `parent_id` as column name, change it according to your column name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public function insert_doc_control_review(Request $request)
{
    $form_data = array(
        'comment' => $request->comment,
        'assigned_to' => $request->assigned_to,
        'revision' => $request->revision,
        'file_id' => $request->file_id,
        'attachment' => $request->attachment,
        'phase_id' => $request->phase_id,
        'review_date' => $request->review_date,
        'due_date' => $request->due_date,
        'completed_date' => $request->completed_date,
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'doc_number' => $this->getNextDocRevNumber()
    );
    $lastId = DocumentControlReview::create($form_data);

    $archive_data = array(
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'iso_management_id' => $request->iso_management_id,
        'phase_id' => $request->phase_id,
        'initial_approval_id' => $request->initial_approval_id,
        'review_id' => $request->review_id,
        'final_approval_id' => $request->final_approval_id,
        'awaiting_release_id' => $request->awaiting_release_id,
        'release_id' => $request->release_id,
        'project_id' => $request->project_id,
        'folder_id' => $request->folder_id,
        'file_id' => $request->file_id,
        'document_control_review_id' => $lastId->id
    );

    DocumentRecordArchive::create($archive_data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have well formed relations in both models, another way can be:

```
$formData = [
    'comment' => $request->comment,
    'assigned_to' => $request->assigned_to,
    'revision' => $request->revision,
    'file_id' => $request->file_id,
    'attachment' => $request->attachment,
    'phase_id' => $request->phase_id,
    'review_date' => $request->review_date,
    'due_date' => $request->due_date,
    'completed_date' => $request->completed_date,
    'user_id'  =>  Auth::id(),
    'doc_number' => $this->getNextDocRevNumber(),
];

$documentControlReview = DocumentControlReview::create($formData);

$archiveData = [
    'user_id'  =>  Auth::id(),
    'iso_management_id' => $request->iso_management_id,
    'phase_id' => $request->phase_id,
    'document_control_review_id' => $request->document_control_review_id,
    'initial_approval_id' => $request->initial_approval_id,
    'review_id' => $request->review_id,
    'final_approval_id' => $request->final_approval_id,
    'awaiting_release_id'  => $request->awaiting_release_id,
    'release_id'  => $request->release_id,
    'project_id' => $request->project_id,
    'folder_id' => $request->folder_id,
    'file_id' => $request->file_id,
];

$documentControlReview->documentRecordArchive()->create(archiveData);
```

For this working you need to have:

```
// DocumentControlReview::class
public function documentRecordArchive
{
    return $this->hasOne(DocumentRecordArchive::class, 'parent_id');
}
// or
public function documentRecordArchives
{
    return $this->hasMany(DocumentRecordArchive::class, 'parent_id');
}
// one of these two regarding which relation is set in business model 1:n or m:n

// DocumentRecordArchive::class
public function documentControlReview()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(DocumentControlReview::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

Also, if child record in DB is mandatory, it is smart to set all transactions into try catch block:

```
try {
    \DB::beginTransaction();

    // make parent insertion
    // make child insertion
    // make another related DB actions if needed

    // all good
    \DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // nothing will be applied, something went wrong with one DB transaction
    \DB::rollback();
    // return redirect()->back()->with('error', $e->getMessage());
}
```

What is main thing I want to point here is that you don't need to use parentId value in array of child's data because it will be recognised as well and it is in some hand more secure - there is no way wrong `parentId` would be applied.

```
$firstTransaction->relationFromModel()->create($dataWithoutFirstTransactionIdBecauseItIsAlreadyAppliedThisWay);
```